# Python: Delete shared variables and clean the shared memory used by the variables in each loop

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

In python, I am trying to create a shared variable that can be accessed by multiple processors. The work will be looped many times. I want to delete shared variables and clean the shared memory used by the variables in each loop. Can anyone help?

Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Python 2.7.6

Numpy 1.11.1

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import ctypes
import os


def parallel_doSomeWork(train_data):

    #...
    #...
    #...
    train_data[0, 0 ,0] = 1.0

def main():



    for n in range(10):

        # print memory usage info, the shared memory is supposed to be zero here
        os.system("free -g")

        # creating shared varibale train_data, that can be accessed by multiprocessors
        train_data_s = mp.Array(ctypes.c_float, 160000 * 64 * 64)
        train_data = np.frombuffer(train_data_s.get_obj(), dtype=np.float32).reshape(160000, 64, 64, 1)

        # print memory usage info, the shared memory is supposed to be used here

        parallel_doSomeWork(train_data)

        # how to delete shared variables and clean the shared memory used by the variables in each loop?
        # To make shared = 0 at next print

        #.......
        #.......
        #.......
        del train_data_s, train_data

        # print memory usage info, the shared memory is supposed to be zero here
        os.system("free -g")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you using `multiprocessing` when all your code is in the same process?

Comment: the function `parallel_doSomeWork` is actually a parallel function, which will pass the shared variable `train_data` to different processors. The parallel function detail is not included here for simplicity.

Comment: I think how you spin off the processes, and whether you wait for them to finish, is important here

Comment: The most import thing is, why the shared memory used by `train_data` is not set free automatically after the function `parallel_doSomeWork(train_data)` executed, even in this simple case as in my attached code

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `close()` on each instance using the shared memory buffer (maybe only one in your case), then call `unlink()` only once to free up that memory. See the docs here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory.unlink